# c# - dll not working properly

Tags: c#, dll

Didn't know which title to set, because I don't exactly know what is the problem.
I had a working `c#` code, i wrapped it into `dll` to separate client from other functions, but now it doesn't work like intended. It is a client-server over `udp`. Here is my code:

```
HandlerFactory factory = new HandlerFactory();
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Options, () => new OptionsHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Unauthorized, () => new UnauthorizedHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Ok, () => new OkHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Invite, () => new InviteHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Bye, () => new ByeHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Error, () => new ErrorHandler());

        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


        Client client = new Client(factory);
        client.Start();
        client.Register();
```

And in client:

```
    private void Listen()
    {
        while (!_stopping)
        {
            try
            {
                var asyncResult = MyUdpClient.BeginReceive(HandleIncomingUdpRequest, null);
                WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { _stopHandle, asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Date:" + DateTime.Now + "\r\nError:" + ex.Message + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
        MyUdpClient.Close();
    }

private void HandleIncomingUdpRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var received = MyUdpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref _serverAddress);
            var requestString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
            var type = Helper.GetRequestType(requestString);
            if (type != RequestType.Trying && type != RequestType.Unknown)
            {
                ProcessRequest(type, requestString);
            }
        }
```

So, i wrapped it into dll, and now use it like this:

```
        var factory = new Factory.HandlerFactory();
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Options, ()=> new OptionsHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Unauthorized, () => new UnauthorizedHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Ok, () => new OkHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Invite, () => new InviteHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Bye, () => new ByeHandler());
        factory.RegisterHandler(RequestType.Error, () => new ErrorHandler());
        Client cl = new Client(factory);
        cl.Start();
        cl.Register();
        cl.Call("2");
```

The problem is, on `cl.Call("2")` i get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll" in

```
                var received = MyUdpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref _serverAddress);
```

And in Register(), client should send Register Request, get response that he is not Unauthorized and call UnauthorizedHandler, but this is not happening.

Comment: You need to inspect the call stack in the exception to determine *which* type has been disposed - that will probably enable you to find out what's happening.

Comment: i debugged dll and found what was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was - I don't know how it happened - in this code:

```
private void Listen()
    {
        while (!_stopping)
        {
            try
            {
                var asyncResult = MyUdpClient.BeginReceive(HandleIncomingUdpRequest, null);
                WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { _stopHandle, asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Date:" + DateTime.Now + "\r\nError:" + ex.Message + "\r\n");
                }
            }
            MyUdpClient.Close();
        }
    }
```

`MyUdpClient.Close()` was called inside the loop. I must have changed `try-catch` blocks and accidentally put that inside the loop, and when I asked this question i copypasted it from different source.

Answer (score 1):

Just from the specified line and your description, I would check if `ref _serverAddress` is correctly initialized as it seems to be global variable that is most probably inited in your main app but you have moved the usage out to the dll.

Comment: Just to improve your code in your answer, call MyUdpClient.Close(); in finally block of try-catch.